# Vue3/Javascript - Unable to create an input that only excepts numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a project with a input that only excepts numbers.

Inside the template I have defined a input with the value set to the variable that is being changed and the input being set to the function that checks if it is a number:

```
      <input
        :value="ie"
        @input="(evt) => changeIE(evt)"
        type="number"
        min="0"
      />
```

Then in the setup function I have declared a ref `ie`. This contains the actual value that is being set by the input. I also have declared the `changeIE' function. Here I first get the input text from the evt. Then I check if the last entered character is a number. If not I remove the last character from the string. The next step is to parse the string to an Integer. And lastly I set the value of the variable to the new value of the input.

```
    const ie = ref('');

    const changeIE = (evt) => {
      let value = 0;
      let input = evt.target.value;

      let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(input[input.length - 1]);

      if (!isnum) input = input.slice(0, -1);

      if (input !== '') value = parseInt(input);

      ie.value = value;
    };
```

The problem is that the input keeps on excepting non numerical numbers even tough I check if they are numbers and if not I remove that character from the string.

Comment: well you created your ref as a string first of all change that to a number and secondly why not use a v-model? :)

Comment: @halilcakar I cannot use a v-model because there is some extra code that prohibits the use of v-model.

Comment: Do you mean you want your field to *except* numbers (i.e, disallow them) or *accept* (allow) them? You words say the former but the code says the latter.

Comment: @kindall My input field must only accept numbers.

Comment: @kindall I was about to edit the title/question for that, but good point, OP could mean either... I just assumed they meant accept.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `v-model` with [number](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#number) as modifier and set initial value to 0 :

```
  <input
    v-model.number="ie"
    type="number"
    min="0"
  />
```

and :

```
const ie=ref(0)
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/rNmPYjx)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! But because of some code that is not contained with the problem, I cannot use v-model.

Comment: Even if I use v-model. Then the input still excepts non numerical characters

Comment: If I use the code you have provides. Then if I enter a non-numerical character into the input it is still shown inside the input.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. As you can see it is still possible to enter non-numeric characters into the input.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
const ie = ref(null) // instead of ref('')
```

By default you set it to a string